# Extract data from a string

Tags: c#, json

I have a data string as

> ```
>  [{"Name":"Jon","Age":"30"},{"Name":"Smith","Age":"25"}]
> ```

How to extract the data from it?

Please suggest me.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/9b9dty7d.aspx not to be rude, but have you tried googling?

Comment: try using Json.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using builtin .NET classes, you can use `System.Web.Extensions`

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code, you can deserialise the JSON i.e.

```
public void GetPersonFromJson(string json)
{
    //...
    json = " [{\"Name\":\"Jon\",\"Age\":\"30\"},{\"Name\":\"Smith\",\"Age\":\"25\"}]";

    JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Person[] person = oJS.Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
    //...
}
```

Or using NewtonSoft Nuget package:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Again in your code, you can deserialise using the `NewtonSoft` library i.e.

```
public void GetPersonFromJson(string json)
{
    //...
    json = " [{\"Name\":\"Jon\",\"Age\":\"30\"},{\"Name\":\"Smith\",\"Age\":\"25\"}]";
    var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **deserialize** the JSON into C# objects. [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is an excellent library for working with JSON.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{"Name":"Jon","Age":"30"}";

Person x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);

string name = x.Name;
```